# Why material lab autocomplete drop-down text is transparent for multiple selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxestags-material-demo-forked-m19vj?file=/demo.js

The code below for autocomplete component was working fine in functionality point of view.
But, the drop-down texts are transparent. How to fix this without changing any library?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Material-UI v4 but you followed v5's API. Autocomplete's `renderOption` API has changed in v5. Here's the API you should use
`function(option: T, state: object) => ReactNode`.

Comment: I was searching the docs for that, but i'm not getting it. can u kindly share the link.

Comment: Yes, https://v4.mui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes